# WordPress get child of child category for drop down

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the child of child categories to populate a drop down, I'm struggling to separate the different categories in a foreach loop - currently my code looks like:

```
<?php

                $taxonomy = 'anatomy';
                $parents  = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'parent' => 0, "hide_empty" => 0 ) ); // Get all top level terms of a taxonomy

                if ( $parents ) :
                ?>
                    <select name="anatomy" id="Anatomy">
                      <option value="">Anatomy</option>
                        <?php foreach ( $parents as $term ) { ?>
                             <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    <?php  $states = get_term_children( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
                    <select name="state" id="state" disabled="disabled">
                      <option value="">Choose a state</option>
                        <?php foreach ( $states as $child ) { 
                                      $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy ); ?>
                                  <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                    </select>

                <?php endif;?>
                <select name="diagnosis" id="diagnosis" disabled="disabled">
                  <option value="">Diagnosis</option>
                 POPULATE WITH CHILD OF CHILD CATEGORIES
                </select>
```

Any help would be great - thanks :)

Comment: you must create recursive function.

Comment: What is your hierarchy? Is it parent->state->diagnosis? What is each of the <selects>s supposed to have? All children, or only children of a selected parent?

Comment: How would that work when child of child cats are considered?

Comment: @bobdye - It is parent->state->diagnosis. each select is supposed to have the first parent, first state of parent and first diagnosis of state. I'll fire of an ajax call to update the state/ child dependant upon change - but I just need to be able to separate the categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your comment answer correctly, it seems like it would be:

```
$taxonomy = 'anatomy';
$parents  = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'parent' => 0, "hide_empty" => 0 ) ); // Get all top level terms of a taxonomy

if ( $parents ) :
    ?>
    <select name="anatomy" id="Anatomy">    
        <option value="">Anatomy</option>
        <?php foreach ( $parents as $term ) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php $firstParent = $parents[0]; ?>
    <?php $states = get_term_children( $firstParent->term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
    <select name="state" id="state" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">Choose a state</option>
        <?php foreach ( $states as $child ) { 
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy ); ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php $firstState = $states[0]; ?>
    <?php $diags = get_term_children( $firstState ->term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
    <select name="diagnosis" id="diagnosis" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">Diagnosis</option>
        <?php foreach ( $diags as $child ) { 
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy ); ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php endif;?>
```